# How can I keep my natural dish soap from going bad?

Tags: cleaning

I bought some biodegradable/natural dish soap from the brand BioVert. I put it in a squeeze bottle left over from some other dish soap, and after some time (maybe 2 months?) there started to be blue dots inside the bottle and the soap itself turned cloudy and tinted blue. How do I keep this from happening in the future?

Comment: Someone downvoted the answer about switching, but this is a behavior I've never seen in any of the natural dish soaps I've used (about a half dozen brands - maybe more). Have you tried any other brands?

Comment: @Nick I did try one other brand but I don't remember what it was. I put the BioVert (purchased in a bulk container) into the bottle it used to be in and removed the label.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions that get at your actual question, but I'd say that whenever you finish with the BioVert, try another brand to see if you get the same results. Maybe in the meantime, someone familiar with that product will come through and answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps storing the soap in the refrigerator or freezer will slow the degradation of the soap. I am not familiar with the biodegrading process for BioVert, but in many cases, chilling a material slows the chemical reactions that take place.

The soap is designed to biodegrade... It just seems like it's degrading too fast for you.